# Use of double vs Double in variable declaration

Tags: java, wrapper, tostring

I was trying to create this program with `d` declared as `double` and not `Double`, could you please tell me why this program does not run. Isn't it supposed to be automatically wrapped and unwrapped, something like boxing and unboxing of primitive data type?
P.S. - I am new to Java I don't remember what it is actually known as but I read somewhere this being referred as boxing and unboxing of primitive types to run methods on them.

```
public class ToStringDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double d = 858.48;
        String s = d.toString();

        int dot = s.indexOf('.');

        System.out.println(dot + " digits " +
            "before decimal point.");
        System.out.println( (s.length() - dot - 1) +
            " digits after decimal point.");
    }
}
```

Note - Above program gives error at `String s = d.toString();`

Comment: I think you need to use `String.valueOf(...)` to convert your double to string.

Comment: @PradeepSimha it isn't nassecary. The simple way: String s = ""+d; works too.

Answer (score 2):

> String s = d.toString();

It is error prone code, as `double` cannot be dereferenced. Explicitly you have to box it to `Double`. `((Double)d).toString()`.

`double` is primitive type, it does not have `toString` method. Only object contains methods. And `toString` is method of `Object` class, you can use `Double` which has `toString` method.

```
Double d = 858.48;
String s = d.toString();
```

Comment: ok but what happens when we print in SOP , double d=3.4; Sysout(d); , then also toString() is called upon it , the question is why doesn't boxing takes place ??

Answer (score 1):

You can't call methods on primitive types like `double` - whereas you can call them on the wrapper types like `Double`. That's why the code you've given doesn't work.

Boxing does happen automatically - but only when you've effectively given it the target for a conversion. For example, you can use:

```
double d = 858.48;
Double boxed = d;
String text = boxed.toString();
```

... but that intermediate conversion to `Double` doesn't happen without being mentioned in the code. You can still do it in one line, of course:

```
String text = ((Double) d).toString();
```

You don't need to box at all to convert the value to a string, mind you:

```
String text1 = String.valueOf(d);
String text2 = Double.toString(d);
```

... will both work too.

Answer (score 1):

`double` is a primitive datatype, whereas `Double` is a wrapper class. Using Double empowers you to invoke methods like `toString()`. You can do something like

```
Double d = 2.4;
d.toString();
```

But you can't do something like

```
double d = 2.4;
d.toString();    // Generates compile time error.
```

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
 public class ToStringDemo {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    double d = 858.48;
    String s = String.valueOf(d);
    int dot = s.indexOf('.');
    System.out.println(dot + " digits " +
        "before decimal point.");
    System.out.println( (s.length() - dot - 1) +
        " digits after decimal point.");
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not being autoboxed because there is no `Double` reference. Try `((Double)d).toString()`

Answer (score 0):

d.toString(); will not work as d is a primitive type. You can call .toString function on objects only. So if you use Double, which is an object and not primitive, your code will work. It has nothing to do with autoboxing.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the program will not run is because you are trying to call a method on a primitive data type. Capital D double represents a double object, which functions similarly to the primitive double variable in that it stores double values, but with the added feature that you may call predefined methods on it.

If you would like to use the double primitive you could do something like this:

```
double aDouble = 100;
String aString = Double.toString(aDouble);
```

The primitive is passed as a parameter to the method on the Double object which will return a string.